# Цвет в textarea и placeholder+

Tags: html, css

Друзья, у меня есть textarea и я задал в нем цвет через color: #333; и еще приделал в него Placeolder, но проблема в том что и цвет подсказок изменился на такой же - что трудно отличить подсказку от введенного цвета, подскажите как быть в этой ситуации, что наджо прописать ?

Comment: @oldzas, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести, приведите используемый код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменить цвет подсказки?

```
-moz-placeholder{
    color: red;
}

-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color: red;
}
```

[Примерный пример на примерах :3](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/verstka-form/about-cross-browser-placeholder.html)

Comment: @ZekMan, на моей памяти 5 мажорных браузеров.

Comment: Ну мне за Вас все писать? Я Вам направление дал, дальше уж и самим можно поискать.

Comment: @ZekMan, за меня? Я вроде не просил за меня делать. Я всего-лишь сделал замечание. А по поводу за кого писать - к тс обращайтесь, а не ко мне.

Comment: в 2017 году уже не работают эти примеры. нужно искать дальше и глубже.